# Python or bash: Merging two csv files based on several matching field values, formatting, the outputting CSV

Tags: python, bash, sorting, join, csv

My preference would be for this to be in Python since I am working on learning more.  If you can provide help in bash that would still be helpful, though.

I've looked around Stack Overflow and found some helpful things but not enough for me to finish this.

I have two CSV files with some shared fields.  The data is not `INT`.  I would like to join based on matching 3 specific fields and write it out to a new `output.csv` when all the processing is done.

`sourceA.csv` looks like this:

```
fieldname_1,fieldname_2,fieldname_3,fieldname_4,fieldname_5,fieldname_6,fieldname_7,fieldname_8,fieldname_9,fieldname_10,fieldname_11,fieldname_12,fieldname_13,fieldname_14,fieldname_15,fieldname_16
```

`sourceB.csv` looks like this:

```
fieldname_4,fieldname_5,fieldname_OTHER,fieldname_8,fieldname_16
```

As you can see, `sourceB.csv` has 4 field names that are also in `sourceA.csv` and one field name that does not.  The data in `fieldname_OTHER` will need to replace the data in `sourceA[fieldname_6]`.

The whole process should go like this:

- Replace data in `sourceA[fieldname_6]` with data from `sourceB[fieldname_OTHER]` if all of the following criteria are met:

  ```
  data in sourceA[fieldname_4]=sourceB[fieldname_4]

  data in sourceA[fieldname_8]=sourceB[fieldname_8]

  data in sourceA[fieldname_16]=sourceB[fieldname_16]
  ```

  (The data in `sourceB[fieldname_5]` does not need to be evaluated.)
- If the above criteria aren't met, just replace `sourceA[fieldname_6]` with the text `ANY`.
- Write each processed line out to `output.csv`.

A sample of what I would like the output to be based on the input CSVs and processing outlined above:

```
dataA,dataB,dataC,dataD,dataE,dataOTHER,dataG,dataH,dataI,dataJ,dataK,dataL,dataM,dataN,dataO,dataP
```

I hope the details I've provided haven't made it more confusing than it needs to be.  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Load the csv files into two tables in MYSQL and then do a join.  This type of operation is what relational databases are all about.  If this is something you are going to have to do often, the data belongs in MySQL.

Comment: What are dataA, dataB, etc? What should be done if there are TWO OR MORE matches on those three fields between a sourceA row and a sourceB row? How many rows in each of sourceA and sourceB?

Comment: Using MySQL join does sound like the best advice for this job.

Comment: Please simplify as much as possible. I'm pretty sure not all the fields are relevant for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'd bother with SQL for a one-off merger like this. It's straightforward in python.

Read in both files with the `csv` module, to get two lists. Index sourceA into a dictionary whose key is the tuple of fields that need to be matched. You can then loop over sourceB, find the matching row instantly, and merge into it from sourceB.

When you're done, you can just output the *list* you read from sourceA: the dict and the list point to the same values, which you've now updated.